# duplicates items in array, then show only one of each in tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, duplicates, tableview

Straight to the point : I have a struct of quotes:

```swift
struct Quote {
    var category: String
    var text: string
}
```

then,

```swift
struct QuoteBrain {
    let quote = [
        Quote(category: "Friends", text: "blablabla"),
        Quote(category: "Friends", text: "Blobloblo"),
        Quote(category: "Love", text: "Love U Sooooooo"),
        etc...
    ]
}
```

I want in my tableView to show category but only once... in this case there will be only 2 categories.
and then when you select a category, i want to show all the quotes related to this category...

Can someone help me?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Hi Marianne, welcome to Stackoverflow, the platform for helping you in your code you provide. We are not a "we write code for you"-platform. So please give us code at least where you fill your tableview (might be wrong, might show all) but you show your good will and i will help you i promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `Set`:

```swift
let categories = Set(quote.map { $0.category })
```